# Wild NaNs appear when adding pandas Series as a column to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I struggle with a strange bug I cannot understand. Maybe it's something very basic I overlook. The code is following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    some_numpy_array, 
    columns=[i for i in range(N)])

df.shape
(57058, 20)

some_pd_series.shape
(57058,)

df["Text"] = some_pd_series

sum(some_pd_series.isnull())
0

sum(df["Text"].isnull())
21137
```

`df["Text"]` should be exactly the same as `some_pd_series`, right? So where do all these `NaN`s suddenly come from?

Comment: Whilst the Series shape may be the same you may not have the same index labels, what does `len(df.index.intersection(some_pd_series.index))` show? If it's not the same as 57058 then the index labels are not the same, this will result in `NaN` where index labels exist in your `df` but not in `some_pd_series`

Comment: You can fix this by doing `some_pd_series.index = df.index` then the column assignment will just work

Comment: @EdChum Yes, you're right. Doing `some_pd_series.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` before adding to `df` also did the trick. Thank you sir!

Comment: @machaerus you can post an answer to your own question: it can help people further to explain the issue and the solution you found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @EdChum comment I found out the problem was caused by indices not matching. This happened because previously I had dropped duplicates from `some_pd_series`, which resulted in "holes" in its index.

Possible ways of solving this issue include:

1. `some_pd_series.index = df.index`
2. `some_pd_series.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`